# How to use jquery selectors on list of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
doSomething(checkboxes);
var checked = // get checked checkboxes from checkboxes

// not efficient since we already have all checkboxes
$('.checkboxes:checked');
// not correct,
$(':checked', checkboxes);
// not efficient and can be incorrect
$(':checked', checkboxes.parent());
```

How do I use selectors on the `checkboxes` themselves?

Comment: i'm not understanding the question, can you post the HTML and be more specific, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the checked checkboxes with a filter :

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
doSomething(checkboxes);
var checked = checkboxes.filter(':checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `checkboxes.find(':checked');`